# Write binary data with Haskell to be read by C?

Tags: c, serialization, haskell, binary

I have a file containing a `[Double]` serialized by Data.Binary that I'd like to read with C. That is, I want to write a C program that reads that data into memory as `double[]`. I'm planning on writing a Haskell program to deserialize the data file and then write the binary data into a new, simpler file that I can just directly read into C, but I'm not sure how to write out just the raw binary data (e.g. 8 bytes for a double).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Data.Binary` to serialize `Double` or `Float` values is not great for portability. The `Binary` instances serialize the values in the form obtained by `decodeFloat`, i.e. as a mantissa and an exponent. The mantissa is serialized as an `Integer`. Parsing that is inconvenient. Much better, as has already suggested by ehird, is using a variant that serializes them as the bit-pattern of the IEEE-754 representation, as offered by [cereal-ieee754](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cereal-ieee754) - as ehird reminded me, that has been merged (minus some conversion between floating point and word types) into [cereal](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cereal) - or the already mentioned [data-binary-ieee754](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-binary-ieee754). Another option is serializing them as strings via `show`. That has the advantage of avoiding any endianness problems.

Comment: By the way, cereal-ieee754's functionality was recently merged into cereal proper.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I forgot. Unfortunately the `Word64 <-> Double` and `Word32 <-> Float` conversions were removed, and they are the only things I'd be interested in in either package ;)

Comment: Yeah, it would be nice if those were split out into a separate package that the serialisation libraries could depend on.

Answer (score 8):

You can reuse `Data.Binary` for the purpose with the [data-binary-ieee754](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-binary-ieee754) package, which allows serialising `Float`s and `Double`s as their IEEE representation. For example:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Binary.Put
import Data.Binary.IEEE754
import Control.Monad

putRawDoubles :: [Double] -> Put
putRawDoubles xs = do
  putWord64le $ genericLength xs
  mapM_ putFloat64le xs
```

It would be nice if there was an analogue of `putWord64host` for `Double`s in data-binary-ieee754, but since there isn't I just went with little-endian. If you want to be portable across endiannesses without explicitly handling the conversion in your C program, you could try `putWord64host . doubleToWord` (`doubleToWord` is also from `Data.Binary.IEEE754`). Though I think that integer endianness differs from floating-point endianness on some platforms...

Incidentally, I would suggest using a format like this even for your regular serialisation; IEEE floats are universal, and binary's default floating-point format is wasteful (as Daniel Fischer points out).

You might also want to consider the [cereal](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cereal) serialisation library, which is faster than binary, better-maintained (binary hasn't been updated since 2009) and has IEEE float format support [built-in](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/cereal/latest/doc/html/Data-Serialize-IEEE754.html).

Comment: There are or were a very few platforms with different float and integer endianness. I forgot which. But these beasts are too rare to worry about.